# Ionic 7 - Download and play mp3 file with audio controls

Tags: android, ionic-framework, audio, capacitor, ionic-native

My server has some mp3 files stored.

I want my application to download and store them.

Then, user can select which file to play. I'd like it to be just like Spotify. A list of audios, and user clicks to play the audio.

I'm using [Ionic's native File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/file) to save the file, in `this.file.dataDirectory`

**Downloading files**

```
this.http.sendRequest(url, {method: "get", responseType: "arraybuffer"}).then(
    res => {
      let blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'audio/mp3'});
      this.saveFile(blob);
    }
);
```

**Saving files**

```
this.file.createFile(folderPath, fileName, true).then(
    _ => {
      if(blob == null) {
        console.error("Downloaded file is null");
        reject(false);
      } else {
        this.file.writeFile(folderPath, fileName, blob, {replace: true}).then(_ => {
          console.log("File created");
        });
      }
})
```

I'm getting the "file created" message. Nice! However, I cannot see those files in "Internal Storage -> Android -> io.ionic.starter -> data", but if I use the `this.file.checkFile(folderPath, filename)`, it returns `true`.

**Playing the audio**

This is the nightmare part. When I give an URL to Javascript's `Audio`, it works nicely, just like:

```
let audioAsset = new Audio(audioLink);
audioAsset.play();
```

But it doesn't work with local files!

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/myfile.mp3
```

I tried **NativeAudio**, but I get the "FileNotFoundException". It worked when I had my audio files already added in assets folder, but not to those I download to "dataDirectory".

Some forums mention `MediaObject`, just like [THIS ONE](https://enappd.com/blog/spotify-like-music-in-ionic-4-apps/48/). However, there is no `@ionic-native/media` package anymore. It seems to be an [Enterprise Feature](https://ionic.io/docs/supported-plugins/media) now.

This should be a very simple task, but it is becoming a nightmare with Ionic! Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue after several hours. Here are some hints to make the Ionic developer's life easier.

**Downloading a file:** Use [Native HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/http)

```
import { HTTP } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) { }

this.http.sendRequest(url, {method: "get", responseType: "arraybuffer"}).then(
  res => { this.saveFile(new Blob([res.data], {type: 'audio/mp3')) }
);
```

**Saving a file:** use [Native File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/file) and *externalApplicationStorageDirectory* as your folder

```
import { File } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file/ngx';

constructor(private file: File) {}

saveFile(blob) {
  let path = this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;
  let filename = 'myfile.mp3';
  this.file.writeFile(path, filename, blob, {replace: true}).then(res => {/*code here*/})
}
```

And finally, **PLAYING THE AUDIO:** Turns out that *Media* was not only an Enterprise feature. [HERE](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/media) is the community version. It was hard to find. Bad job, Ionic...

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/media/ngx';
import { File } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file/ngx';

constructor(private media: Media, private file: File) {}

playSound() {
  let path = this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;
  let filepath = `${path}/myfile.mp3`;
  let file: MediaObject = this.media.create(filepath);
  file.play();
}
```

And DO NOT forget to set the permissions. Here are mine:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

**BONUS ROUND:** Audio controls on the notification bar are awesome, right? There is a [MediaSession API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) plugin for cordova [HERE](https://github.com/daubit/capacitor-media-session). Many thanks to [THIS GUY](https://github.com/jofr/capacitor-media-session) too.